# understand simple makefile

Tags: make

```
.PHONY:hello
hello:c_mem.c
    cc  c_mem.c -o c_mem
```

make command will generate file c_mem.

```
.PHONY:hello
hello:c_mem.c
    cc  c_mem.c
```

make command will generate file a.out.

---

all these seems make sense for me. However from manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Introduction.html

> A target is usually the name of a file that is generated by a program;
> examples of targets are executable or object files. A target can also
> be the name of an action to carry out, such as ‘clean’ (see Phony
> Targets).
>
> A prerequisite is a file that is used as input to create the target. A
> target often depends on several files.

PHONY: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145590/what-is-the-purpose-of-phony-in-a-makefile
So I am not sure

```
.PHONY:hello
hello:c_mem.c
    cc  c_mem.c -o c_mem
```

the **:hello** and **hello:** mean?

---

can I interpret the makefile as

> The whole project name alias as **hello**, in hello for file c_mem.c
> do the following command
>
> ```
> cc  c_mem.c -o c_mem
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makefiles are interpreted as follows:

```
target: <dependencies>
  commands to produce target
```

- The colon `:` always belong to the target.
- All dependencies will be checked (for file date) when building the target, so all needed dependencies will automatically be updated **if needed**.
- When dependencies have been re-built (are more recent than target), execute the commands listed

As stated in the article under the link you supplied:

```
PHONY targets are not associated with (output) files
```

So you are always able to build the target, independent of file dates, when needed (eg.: `make clean`):

```
.PHONY: clean
clean:
   rm -rf build/*
```

I would suggest to use `CMake` though, which is a generator for `Makefiles`, but much more understandable in Syntax. `Makefiles`can get quite messy.

Comment: So this command can be explain as for *c_mem.c* do command: *cc  c_mem.c -o c_mem*?

Comment: For target `hello` look after changes in `c_mem.c`. If `c_mem.c` is newer than the targets (that should be `c_mem:  ... `) then run the associated command `cc c_mem.c -o c_mem`.